# Javascript & DOM (Pannellum custom Hotspot)

Tags: javascript, dom, pannellum

I'm using Pannellum.js to elaboratesome 360 images as equirectangular images on a browser. My main problem is on DOM when i try to show/hide some elements i'm generating dinamically. I'm trying to achieve this goal using the javascript call document.getElementById(elemId).style.visibility = visible/hidden.

In particular what i'm trying to achieve is to show the span over the exclamation mark that is, for css default, hidden. (See the fiddle).

In the console i can see that the inline style have been modified but the element on the screen is still hidden.

This is the function i'm using to hide/show DOM elements

```
function updateHTML(elmId, value) {
  var elem = document.getElementById(elmId);
  if (typeof elem !== 'undefined' && elem !== null) {
    document.getElementById(elmId).style.visibility = value;
    console.log(elem);
  }
}
```

This is the link to my example

[Fiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/boLtzbvq/)

I have similiar example too that is working  as intended but in this case i'm not generating dynamic content.

[Fiddle Demo Working as intended](https://jsfiddle.net/Lxu2q3pu/)

Comment: So what do we need to do to reproduce the issue in your fiddles - hover stuff, click somewhere, ...?

Comment: FYI, you currently linked to the same fiddle twice.